# system and its subsystems: a probability problem

Tags: probability

A system consisted of sub-system $1,2,3$, these three subsystems are independent and will operate successfully a year with a probability of $0.75$, $0.85$ and $0.9$.

(1) Calculate the probability that the system will operate successfully for a year.

(2) A company buys $10$ of these systems, calculate the probability

(a) All systems works.

(b) At least one system works.

(c) Two of the ten system works.

my try: (1) $0.75\times 0.85\times 0.9$

Didn't even understand what the problem 2 wants to answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

It should be read as $3$ subquestions. For example in $2a$, it asks for the "probability that all systems works".

You have computed the probability that a system to work, $p$. Whether a particular system work follows Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$.

Now you have $n=10$ identical and independent systems.  Can you identify the distribution that corresponds to the sum of $n$ independent Bernoulli distributions?

So $p= 0.75\times 0.85\times 0.9$ and $n=10$

So $X\sim\text{Bin}(10,p)$. We have $P(X=x)= \begin{pmatrix} n\\r\end{pmatrix}p^x(1-p)^{10-x}$

All system works: $P(X= 10)$

At least one: $P(X\ge 1)=1- P(X=0)$

Two of the ten system works: $P(X=2)$

Comment: Binomial distribution? So

Comment: Could you please give me answer.

Comment: yes, binomial distribution is correct. where do you have difficulty in applying the formula?

Comment: I updated answer, correct me

Comment: If all the system work, it shoud be $P(X=10)$.